# sql top 1 based on group records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table `ProductMst`  (combination is unique - CodeNum, MainCatid, SubCatid)

```
id  CodeNum     MainCatid   SubCatid    Desc        Qty
1   001         1           1           prod1       5
2   001         1           2           prod2       10
3   001         2           3           prod3       1
4   002         2           3           prod4       2
5   003         2           3           prod5       3
6   004         1           1           prod6       4
```

Sub Table `SubCatMst`

```
id  name    subcode
1   scat1   00
2   scat2   00
3   scat3   02
4   scat4   03
```

Desired Result

```
id  CodeNum     MainCatid   SubCatid    Desc        Qty     subcode
2   001         1           2           prod2       15      00
3   001         2           3           prod3       1       02
4   002         2           3           prod4       2       02
5   003         2           3           prod5       3       02
6   004         1           1           prod6       4       00
```

Basically, i wanted to group `subcode` if same and `sum (Qty)` based on `subcode`. And, take the `TOP 1` records data as all columns based on `MAX(Qty)`.

Summary: Please check first 2 records which combines.

Query Attempt:

```
select * from (
select A.*, B.subcode, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY A.CodeNum, A.MainCatid, B.subcode ORDER BY A.Qty desc) as row 
from ProductMst A 
inner join SubCatMst B on A.SubCatid=B.id
) as A where row<=1
```

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: @jarlh edited my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question says:

> i wanted to group subcode if same

If what is the same?  I assume this means if `codenum` is the same.

Regardless of the exact field(s), the logic is the same.  You can use window functions to aggregate the data and determine the row to choose:

```
select ps.*
from (select p.*, sc.subcode,
             sum(qty) over (partition by codenum, subcode) as qty,
             row_number() over (partition by codenum, subcode order by qty desc) as seqnum
      from ProductMst p join
           SubCatMst sc
           on p.subcatid = sc.id
     ) ps
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I have tried also similar to your solution, and only was looking for `sum(qty)`.